# Calculate velocity of radon-220 nuclear after decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, velocity, radiation, mass-energy

I cam across the following question whilst doing some physics revision of the [SQA CfE Higher Sample Paper](http://mrmackenzie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/PhysicsSQPH.pdf)

[image: Question]

To solve the question I first worked out the mass difference (md = $5.5×10^{-29} kg$) then using the mass-energy equivalence equation ($E=mc^2$) to calculate the energy released (energy = $4.95×10^{-12} J$). 
I then used Ek = $0.5mv^2$ to calculate the velocity ($v=3.9×10^7 ms^{-1}$). However, the answer in the mark scheme is $2.656×10^5 ms^{-1}$.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: It seems to me you haven't taken into account the kinetic energy of the $\alpha$. $K_T=K_{\mathrm{Ra224}}+K_{\alpha}$.

Comment: In finding the kinetic energy of the Alpha, you will need to take into account its speed since it is moving at relativistic speeds.

Comment: @user1683793 Rest mass of an alpha is almost 4 GeV, kinetic energy typically 1000 times less.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a relativistic problem.  The speeds are <0.9c so there will be no significant special relativistic correction.  And you use of $E=mc^2$ is not correct in this problem.  Simply treat it as a conservation of momentum situation.

Comment: The alpha speed was given as much less than 90 % of c.

Comment: After some calculations, the alpha speed contributes about 0.1% to the mass.  That part is right but since the radium starts at rest, the only place the energy can come from is the E=mc^2 part.

Comment: The mass has been converted to energy and has been converted to the kinetic energy of the two resultant particles.  You are give one of these as the velocity of the alpha particle.  There is no need to deal with it any more.  This is a basic conservation of momentum problem.